# Group and randomize data based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need help with this.
I want to randomize a set of data like the one in the input. The output will have the time column remain the same but the  data that is not zero in the "S" column will be randomly distributed but we keep the number sequence. That is, in the example in the input, we randomly distribute these groups of data (300, 200, 325, 411) and (450,346,250).

The Input:

| time | S |
| --- | --- |
| 2:30 | 0 |
| 2:35 | 0 |
| 2:40 | 300 |
| 2:45 | 200 |
| 2:50 | 325 |
| 2:55 | 411 |
| 3:00 | 0 |
| 3:05 | 0 |
| 3:10 | 450 |
| 3:15 | 346 |
| 3:20 | 250 |
| 3:25 | 0 |
| 3:30 | 0 |

This is what I was thinking...

Steps:

1. Grouping the non-zero sequence : This is the part I can't quite figure out
2. Randomizing the group

```
import random

random.shuffle(groups)
```

Note: Please if you think there's another way to approach the problem I'm all ears.

Possible Output:

| time | S |
| --- | --- |
| 2:30 | 300 |
| 2:35 | 200 |
| 2:40 | 325 |
| 2:45 | 411 |
| 2:50 | 0 |
| 2:55 | 0 |
| 3:00 | 450 |
| 3:05 | 346 |
| 3:10 | 250 |
| 3:15 | 0 |
| 3:20 | 0 |
| 3:25 | 0 |
| 3:30 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create consecutive groups by compare by `0` and chain shifted values by `|` for regex `OR` with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then change order by random values:

```
m = df.S.eq(0)
s = (m | m.shift()).cumsum()
ids = s.unique()
np.random.shuffle(ids)
df = df.set_index(s).loc[ids].reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
    time    S
0   2:30    0
1   2:40  300
2   2:45  200
3   2:50  325
4   2:55  411
5   3:25    0
6   3:10  450
7   3:15  346
8   3:20  250
9   3:05    0
10  2:35    0
11  3:00    0
12  3:30    0
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, the only issue with your solution is that the time column changes. We don't want it to change.

Comment: @codemastro can you try `df = df.set_index(s).loc[ids].assign(time = df['time'].to_numpy()).reset_index(drop=True)` ?